# Деплой при пуше в определенную ветку GitlabCI

Tags: php, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Возможно-ли в GitlabCI настроить сборку проекта на определенном сервере при пуше в определенную ветку?
Т.е. есть два сервера и две ветки: prod и test - необходимо, чтобы при пуше в тест происходила сборка на тестовом сервере.
Как должен выглядеть gitlab-ci.yml? Буду рад ссылкам, примерам и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать параметр `only`. В значении указать имя ветки, например:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
   stage: test
   script:
     - echo 'testing...'

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - test-branch
  script:
    - echo 'deploying...'
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

Comment: т.е. можно делать сколько угодно веток и столько же блоков подобных deploy с разными only?

Comment: @ДенисНестерюк, думаю, что да